# StyleSelector and return style from XAML

Tags: wpf, styles

I created a style in XAML, How Can I return this style in style selector (code)?

I created style in XAML and I want to only return the style which is declared in XAML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to access the XAML resource where you stored the style. Generally they way to do this is store it in a seperate resources file. Then you need to access the URI of that XAML file as a ResourceDictionary object. Here is an example where I use a converter to decide which style an element will get.

```
namespace Shared.Converters
{
  public class SaveStatusConverter : IValueConverter
  {

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

      bool? saveState = (bool?)value;
      Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/Shared;component/Styles.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
      ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
      if (saveState == true)
        return resourceDictionary["GreenDot"] as Style;
      if (saveState == false)
        return resourceDictionary["RedDot"] as Style;
      return resourceDictionary["GrayDot"] as Style;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add a property to your `StyleSelector` and then use the property to pass a reference to the `Style` in XAML.

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    private Style styleToUse;

    public Style StyleToUse
    {
        get { return styleToUse; }
        set { styleToUse = value; }
    }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return styleToUse;
    }
}

<Control StyleSelector="{DynamicResource myStyleSelector}">
    <Control.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyle">
        ...
        </Style>
        <local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="myStyleSelector" StyleToUse="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
    </Control.Resources>
</Control>
```

Comment: Is there any way to support using StyleToUse="{DynamicResource myStyle}"?

Comment: @sam: I think `StyleToUse` would have to be a dependency property to allow using `DynamicResource`. But then `MyStyleSelector` would have to be derived from `DependencyObject`. But we need it to be derived from `StyleSelector` to use it as a style selector. I don't know how this can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for an example, here's a relatively usable one:

http://www.shujaat.net/2010/10/wpf-style-selector-for-items-in.html

If you have more specific questions, I would suggest posting some code/XAML to indicate what you've tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: I created style in XAML and I want to only return the style which is declared in XAML.